# How to recreate the Freak attack?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, apache

Currently I am trying to recreate the Freak attack on a virtual machine. For this purpose I set up a Linux Mint 17.1 system with **Apache 2.4.7** (with a self signed certificate) and **OpenSSL 1.0.1f**.
I also modified the ssl.conf to get the following cipher suite:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:+EXP:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+eNULL
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Now there is a way to check if you are vulnerable to the Freak attack by performing the following command:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -cipher EXP
```

If the attack works a connection should be established. (according to this article: http://penguinsforall.blogspot.de/2015/03/freak-factoring-attack-on-rsa-export.html)
Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140268021556896:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3     alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:770:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 111 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

That means the server if not vulnerable. Could you help me try to understand why the attack does not work on this system configuration?

Comment: Now I installed an old Debian version (6.x) with an old Apache server (included in the image). And suddenly I could connect with the exported cipher suite. Maybe newer versions of Apache are secure to this kind of attack.